# Flutter Firebase whereIN 10 limit Problem

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have id list like this;

`List<dynamic> saveIDList = [];` The values ​​in this list change according to the id saved by the user.

I try to show the posts saved by the user. So I create a query like this;

```
 Query saveIDRef = _firestore
              .collectionGroup("Posts")
              .where("postID", whereIn: saveIDList);
```

After creating this query, I call the saveIDRef in the stream builder. So far, there is no problem in my code, it works properly, but when the length of the saveIDlist exceeds 10, I get a warning.

It is not possible for me to change my database form or the way I query my saveIDList, how can I solve this problem?

I tried different solutions but it didn't work.

For Example I create chunk list like this;

```
var chunks = [];

for (var i = 0; i < saveIDList.length; i += 10) {
      chunks.add(saveIDList.sublist(
          i, i + 10 > saveIDList.length ? saveIDList.length : i + 10));
    }
```

and I seperated values in saveIDList then I used chunks in whereIN query like this;

```
 Query saveIDRef = _firestore
                  .collectionGroup("Posts")
                  .where("postID", whereIn: chunks);
```

But that didn't work either. When I query chunks list like this;

```
Query saveIDRef = _firestore
                      .collectionGroup("Posts")
                      .where("postID", whereIn: chunks[0]);
```

it works. But I want to Query all elements in chunks list not the only first element of chunks list. When I put this code in to the for loop, I get error of whereIN query cannot use more than once.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893744/how-can-i-deal-with-the-firestore-wherein-limit-of-10-when-using-a-switch-stream

Comment: I checked but I cant found a side that can be adapted to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) regarding the simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore, there are some limitations on the logical queries:

> Cloud Firestore provides limited support for logical `OR` queries. The `in`, and `array-contains-any` operators support a logical `OR` of up to 10 equality (`==`) or `array-contains` conditions on a single field. For other cases, create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app.

Thus a possible solution would be to create chunks of your list and query those chunks separately as you have tried. For instance you can use the [List subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) method of the List object to create those sublists or chunks.